# How to send Rest GET request that contains "#" value in url parameters?

Tags: spring, web-services, rest

I'm implementing a spring rest webservice. And when i'm sending a GET request to server using following url, it works fine. But when I'm sending a password with # character, server takes only the characters before the #. How can I send parameter value that contains # character?

```
authentication/authenticate?type=username&username=someuser&password=pass#2033
```

Comment: You need to url encode the `#` character else it will be interpreted as an anchor instead.

Comment: could you please tell me how can i do that? Is this need to be done from client side or server side

Comment: It will never reach the server so it has to be done on the client, also are you sure you want this as part of the URL? I wouldn't use a website or service that would require me to send the username/password as url params.

Comment: thank you for the answer. this service is only for internal usage of an application.

Comment: still sending a username/password is insecure regardless of the internal or external accessibility of a service. Everyone can read the username/password and use a browser to send requests to your internal service. Now what if a disgruntled employee want to do not so nice things....